# Removing u in list

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unicode

I have read up on remove the character 'u' in a list but I am using google app engine and it does not seem to work!

```
def get(self):
    players = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Player")
    print players
    playerInfo  = {}

    test = []

    for player in players:
        email =  player.email
        gem =  str(player.gem)
        a = "{email:"+email + ",gem:" +gem +"}"

        test.append(a)


    ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(test))
    print test
```

Final output:

```
[u'{email:test@gmail.com,gem:0}', u'{email:test,gem:0}', u'{email:test,gem:0}', u'{email:test,gem:0}', u'{email:test,gem:0}', u'{email:test1,gem:0}']
```

Comment: the character "u" isn't in the list, it's in the `repr` of a unicode string, which is what's printed if you try to `print` a whole list.

Comment: The `u` denotes Unicode strings.  It doesn't seem to be a problem by itself that the list contains Unicode strings, so what's your actual issue?

Comment: The code `ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(test))` calculates a value and then throws it away.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

That 'u' is part of the external representation of the string, meaning it's a Unicode string as opposed to a byte string. It's not in the string, it's part of the type.

As an example, you can create a new Unicode string literal by using the same synax. For instance:

```
>>> sandwich = u"smörgås"
>>> sandwich
u'sm\xf6rg\xe5s'
```

This creates a new Unicode string whose value is the Swedish word for sandwich. You can see that the non-English characters are represented by their Unicode code points, ö is `\xf6` and å is `\xe5`. The 'u' prefix appears just like in your example to signify that this string holds Unicode text.

To get rid of those, you need to encode the Unicode string into some byte-oriented representation, such as UTF-8. You can do that with e.g.:

```
>>> sandwich.encode("utf-8")
'sm\xc3\xb6rg\xc3\xa5s'
```

Here, we get a new string without the prefix 'u', since this is a byte string. It contains the bytes representing the characters of the Unicode string, with the Swedish characters resulting in multiple bytes due to the wonders of the UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Don't confuse a Unicode string (an object in memory) and its text representation (that you could use to specify the object in Python source code). Consider `print(sandwich)` vs. `print(repr(sandwich))`. Don't encode text to bytes.

Answer (score 24):

```
arr = [str(r) for r in arr]
```

This basically converts all your elements in string. Hence removes the encoding. Hence the u which represents encoding gets removed
Will do the work easily and efficiently

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: And use StackOverflow's code formatting markdown to code-format your snippets ;)

Answer (score 18):

The u means the strings are unicode.  Translate all the strings to ascii to get rid of it:

```
a.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

Answer (score 13):

`u'AB'` is just a text representation of the corresponding Unicode string. Here're several methods that create exactly the same Unicode string:

```
L = [u'AB', u'\x41\x42', u'\u0041\u0042', unichr(65) + unichr(66)]
print u", ".join(L)
```

#### Output

```
AB, AB, AB, AB
```

There is no `u''` in *memory*. It is just the way to *represent* the `unicode` object in Python 2 (how you would write the Unicode string literal in a Python *source code*). By default `print L` is equivalent to `print "[%s]" % ", ".join(map(repr, L))` i.e., [`repr()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) is called for each list item:

```
print L
print "[%s]" % ", ".join(map(repr, L))
```

#### Output

```
[u'AB', u'AB', u'AB', u'AB']
[u'AB', u'AB', u'AB', u'AB']
```

If you are working in a REPL then a customizable [`sys.displayhook`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook) is used that calls [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) on each object by default:

```
>>> L = [u'AB', u'\x41\x42', u'\u0041\u0042', unichr(65) + unichr(66)]
>>> L
[u'AB', u'AB', u'AB', u'AB']
>>> ", ".join(L)
u'AB, AB, AB, AB'
>>> print ", ".join(L)
AB, AB, AB, AB
```

Don't encode to bytes. [Print unicode directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30551552/4279).

---

In your specific case, I would create a Python list and use `json.dumps()` to serialize it instead of using string formatting to create JSON text:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import json
# ...
test = [dict(email=player.email, gem=player.gem)
        for player in players]
print test
print json.dumps(test)
```

#### Output

```
[{'email': u'test@gmail.com', 'gem': 0}, {'email': u'test', 'gem': 0}, {'email': u'test', 'gem': 0}, {'email': u'test', 'gem': 0}, {'email': u'test', 'gem': 0}, {'email': u'test1', 'gem': 0}]
[{"email": "test@gmail.com", "gem": 0}, {"email": "test", "gem": 0}, {"email": "test", "gem": 0}, {"email": "test", "gem": 0}, {"email": "test", "gem": 0}, {"email": "test1", "gem": 0}]
```

Comment: Thanks, without converting or encoding I directly used it as a key in a dictionary.

Answer (score 6):

```
[u'{email:test@gmail.com,gem:0}', u'{email:test,gem:0}', u'{email:test,gem:0}', u'{email:test,gem:0}', u'{email:test,gem:0}', u'{email:test1,gem:0}']
```

'u' denotes unicode characters. We can easily remove this with map function on the final list element

```
map(str, test)
```

Another way is when you are appending it to the list

```
test.append(str(a))
```

Comment: This basically duplicates an existing answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39771186/874188

Comment: Hey @tripleee try to use timeit for both the solutions. You will be able to see the difference. Map method is faster. And `test.append(str(a))` is creating list simultaneously not iterating upon the list after creating the list hence saving the time.

Answer (score 5):

Please Use `map()` python function.

Input: In case of list of values

index = `[u'CARBO1004' u'CARBO1006' u'CARBO1008' u'CARBO1009' u'CARBO1020']`

```
encoded_string = map(str, index)
```

Output: `['CARBO1004', 'CARBO1006', 'CARBO1008', 'CARBO1009', 'CARBO1020']`

For a Single string input:

```
index = u'CARBO1004'
# Use Any one of the encoding scheme.
index.encode("utf-8")  # To utf-8 encoding scheme
index.encode('ascii', 'ignore')  # To Ignore Encoding Errors and set to default scheme
```

Output: `'CARBO1004'`

Answer (score 4):

You don't "remove the character 'u' from a list", you *encode Unicode strings.* In fact the strings you have are perfectly fine for most uses; you will just need to encode them appropriately before outputting them.

Comment: you don't need to encode a Unicode string; you could print it directly `print(unicode_string)`, [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30551552/4279)

Comment: Depends on where you're outputting it to.

Comment: obviously, though the default is still: use Unicode to work with text in Python. Don't encode to bytes unless necessary ([my answer shows that it is not necessary](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33423708/4279)) -- I'm sure you know the concept of Unicode sandwich

Answer (score -1):

## For python datasets you can use an index.

```
tmpColumnsSQL = ("show columns in dim.date_dim")
hiveCursor.execute(tmpColumnsSQL)
columnlist = hiveCursor.fetchall()

for columns in jayscolumnlist:
    print columns[0]

for i in range(len(jayscolumnlist)):    
    print columns[i][0])
```