# removing `u` character in python output

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, angularjs

I create a form and when I click the submit button, I assign the 3 value into a javascript dict and send it over to a python script to process however My web browser tell me a error!

from Json error:  {u'food': 90, u'cargo': 70, u'fuel': 50} SyntaxError

controller.js

```
function customiseCtrl($xhr){
var self = this;

checkPoint();
this.process = function(){
    if (checkPoint()){

        var newPlayer = {"fuel":value, "food":value2, "cargo":value3 };

        $xhr('POST', '/process', newPlayer, function (code, response) {
            self.x = response;

        });
    }
};


}
```

/process --> python script (I am trying to read the information of "info" and write it into the Google app engine.

```
def post(self):
 user = users.get_current_user()
 player = Player();

 info = json.loads(self.request.body)
 player.fuel = info.fuel
 self.response.out.write(info)
```

Comment: Python's `repr` (which is being implicitly called here) isn't designed to produce JSON.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing u in list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773121/removing-u-in-list)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Printing a Python dict will in many cases not generate valid JSON. You want the `json` module:

```
import json

# ... snip ...

self.response.out.write(json.dumps(info))
# or
json.dump(info, self.response.out)
```

Comment: `json.dump(info, self.response)` might also work if it's a file-like object

Comment: Thanks, added. Is there likely to be a performance difference between the two?

Comment: For complex or large datasets, yes, using `json.dump` will be more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't in the JavaScript (per your original title), it's in the output of the JSON. You need to output properly-formatted [JSON](http://json.org), which if it looks like `{u'food': 90, u'cargo': 70, u'fuel': 50}`, `self.response.out.write(info)` isn't doing. ([jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com) is handy for validating JSON text.)

I'm not much of a python-head (actually, I'm not a python-head at all), but I think you want to replace

```
self.response.out.write(info)
```

with

```
json.dump(info, self.response)
```

..or similar (the above assumes that `self.response` is a *"...a `.write()`-supporting file-like object..."*), based on [this reference](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html).

Comment: I think in order to use `self.response.out` like you do, you need `json.dump`, which writes to a file-like object, not `json.dumps`, which returns a string.

Comment: @nrabinowitz: Actually, when using `.write()` using the `dumps()` method is perfectly fine. But of course using `dump()` is a little bit faster since the json can be written directly to the object without creating a string containing everything. However, with `self.response` probably being a stringio or similar object it won't matter much.