# Python gives output 'u' character before displaying anything?

Tags: python

I am new to python and I am getting something weird stuff in my python console while displaying output into the screen.

```
>>> macbeth_sentsence = gutenberg.sents('shakespeare-macbeth.txt');
>>> macbeth_sentsence
[[u'[', u'The', u'Tragedie', u'of', u'Macbeth', u'by', u'William', u'Shakespeare', u'1603', u']'], [u'Actus', u'Primus', u'.'], ...]
```

I am not expecting the extra 'u' character in my output screen.

Anyone knows how to suppress that? Anything to do with default python settings?

---

### UPDATED from BELOW: for people who didn't understood what I want to resolve.

When the same command was executed in my Windows system in Vbox

I got something like this:

```
>>> macbeth_sentsence = gutenberg.sents('shakespeare-macbeth.txt');
    >>> macbeth_sentsence
    [['[', 'The', 'Tragedie', 'of', 'Macbeth', 'by', 'William', 'Shakespeare', '1603', ']'], ['Actus', 'Primus', '.'], ...]
```

I want the same result in my Mac machine; what adjustment I have to do into my defaults to get result like that I got in Windows.

PS: 
Answers from this: [removing `u` character in python output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791055/removing-u-character-in-python-output)
and this: [Python ascii utf unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27256006/python-ascii-utf-unicode)
and this : [Python string prints as [u'String']](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599625/python-string-prints-as-ustring) are not what I am looking for.

Comment: That just means it's a unicode string.  If you actually print the string using `print`, you don't see that.

Comment: it is a unicode `u` , why do you want to remov them?

Comment: You are seeing the **`repr()`** representation, which provides you with a format that lets you reproduce the value in a new Python session. Always helpful with debugging.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yeah I understand that, but why is it showing in there only for me? I don't see this things in others peers screen, but only mine. 
@larsks~ okay, yeah true, but how shall I remove them? Anything to do with defaults?

Comment: @MartijnPieters good to know that, but I am not debugging right now, can you tell me how to suppress it and use it only when required?

Comment: @ikis: then *don't print the list*. Containers always use `repr()` to represent contents. Print the individual elements or format the list contents into a new string.

Comment: You could `encode()` each string

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: or just not print the list. Or format the contents, using `unicode.join()` perhaps.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yep. I would just leave as is but the OP did ask

Comment: I used `encode` in my answer and I got some downvotes. Any idea Padraic?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Did you understand my question. The one you tagged duplicate with is no way answer to my question. Please check my comment in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It's just indicating a unicode string.
see
[Easiest way to remove unicode representations from a string in python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793973/easiest-way-to-remove-unicode-representations-from-a-string-in-python-3)

Comment: The post you link to has nothing to do with unicode representations in containers like a list.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Unicode string, you can do the following to remove it by converting to ascii:

```
macbeth_sentence = [[i.encode() for i in j] for j in macbeth_sentence]
```

Comment: Revoked down vote, but that didn't answered my question. How to make this change permanent.

Comment: It is permanent. Try printing `new` and you'll see that there is no preceding u.

Comment: I think the OP means how to do it in the original list

Comment: @MalikBrahimi~ By permanent I meant next time if I write something like {>>> macbeth_sentsence = gutenberg.sents('shakespeare-macbeth.txt');
>>> macbeth_sentsence} I don't have to encode macbeth_sentsence, but it should come as default without u.

Comment: Is this good now ikis? I used a list comprehension to iterate through the entire nested list and I encoded every string to ascii.