# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u03c0'

Tags: python-2.7, unicode

I am trying to extract the attribute value `Body` from `row` element in pi.xml.

```
    cat pi.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <posts>
         <row Id="19" Body=" The value of π, the value of pi." />
    </posts>
```

The python file, pi.py :

```
    from lxml import etree
    doc = etree.parse('pi.xml')
    r = doc.findall('row')
    for i in r:
        print (i.get('Body'))
```

And the locale:

```
    $ locale:
    LANG=en_IN
    LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
    LC_CTYPE="en_IN"
    LC_NUMERIC="en_IN"
    LC_TIME="en_IN"
    LC_COLLATE="en_IN"    
    LC_ALL=
```

Upon running `pi.py` as as `python pi.py`, everything is fine.
But, if I try to redirect the output and run pi.py as `python pi.py >> pi.txt` - I get an error message - UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u03c0' in position 101: ordinal not in range(128)

If I change `print (i.get('Body'))`  to  `print (i.get('Body')).encode('utf-8')`   , then `python pi.py >> pi.txt` works fine. But, is this the proper way to do it?

Operating System - Ubuntu.

Comment: Try: `$ PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8 python pi.py >> py.txt`.

Comment: It worked , thanks Mark! But, I haven't got any solution that would work everywhere. When I used this `$ PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8 python somefile.py >> somefile.txt` to other files it didn't work there (same UnicodeEncodeError is thrown) . I'll try finding the solution, if i get one I'll post here.

Comment: If the file explicitly encodes its output, this method wouldn't  work. Scripts should just print Unicode and let the terminal decide the encoding.

Comment: @Mark Tolonen: So, is it correct if i use `x.decode('utf-8')` upon reading 'x' from a utf-8 encoded file and then `print processed_x.encode('utf-8')` to save output to another file? Also, this always works and never gives any error. Looking for your suggestion.

Comment: `print processed_x.encode('utf-8')` works if the console is configured for UTF-8, but it wouldn't work on a console configured for `iso-8859-1`.  Just `print processed_x` will automatically encode for UTF-8 if the console is configured for UTF-8.  Redirection is a shell function, so leave specifying the encoding to the shell also with `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8 python pi.py >> py.txt`.  It also leaves the option open to use other encodings without modifying the script.

Comment: "It also leaves the option open to use other encodings without modifying the script." - This really makes sense. Shall stick to `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8 python pi.py >> pi.txt` while redirecting the output. Thanks, again.

Comment: I turned our conversation into an answer since it solves your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8 python pi.py >> py.txt
```

But if your script explicitly encodes its output, such as:

```
print u'somestring'.encode('utf8')
```

this method won't work. However, scripts should just print Unicode and let the terminal decide the encoding, as in:

```
print u'somestring'
```

Python will automatically encode for UTF-8 if the console is configured for UTF-8.

For your redirection case, Python doesn't know what encoding to use when printing Unicode, so defaults to `ascii`.  Since redirection is a shell function, leave specifying the encoding to the shell using:

```
PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8 python pi.py >> py.txt.
```

This leaves the option open to use other encodings without modifying the script.