# Suppress 'u' in Output - Python

Tags: python, regex, encoding

How can i get rid of these `u` in output?

Regex:

Tregex1 = `"1?\W*([2-9][0-8][0-9])\W*([2-9][0-9]{2})\W*([0-9]{4})(\se?x?t?(\d*))?"`

Code:

```
for a in re.findall(Tregex1,text_value,re.IGNORECASE):
        print a
```

Output:

```
(u'877', u'638', u'7848', u'\n', u'')
(u'650', u'627', u'1000', u'\n', u'')
(u'650', u'627', u'1001', u'\nE', u'')
(u'312', u'273', u'4100', u'', u'')
```

I tried using these & followed several similar [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773121/removing-u-in-list)

```
a.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
a.encode('utf-8')
",".join(a)
```

But none of them are working.

Expected Output:

```
877-638-7848
650-627-1000
650-627-1001
312-273-4100
```

I am using Python 2.7

Also can someone explain, why i am getting sometimes \n while \nE otherwise or even blank?

Comment: You do not have to worry about the `u` prefix, it only tells you the strings are Unicode.

Comment: @downvoter reason please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
for a in re.findall(Tregex1,text_value,re.IGNORECASE):
    print '-'.join(a[:3])
```

the u just tells you that it's a unicode string.

the (..., ...,) is the representation of the tuples

what '-'.join(...) does is connect the strings of ... with a -

a[:3] means "only the first three elements of a"

(for a good explanation of the slicing notation in python look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/327293)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not the `u`. If you want to format your results in a specific way, you should use the string formatting functions.

```
print '-'.join(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

The u just means it is unicode. You can recode it as you wish. This will work, and also skip the blank values:

```
a = (u'877', u'638', u'7848', u'\n', u'')
print "-".join([x.strip() for x in a if x.strip() != u""])
```

> 877-638-7848

Comment: Don't use `is` for string comparisons.

Comment: @Dan I think phogi's answer is more time efficient since it does not bother to check for 4th index