# Django to plot a graph using plotly with data from forms

Tags: javascript, python, django, plot, plotly

I want to plot agraph using plotly.js library and the inputs to the graph is taken from the user through an html form.

I have created a html form to read X and Y values for the plot. In the views.py, i accessed the form data using request.POST.get and then added to a list x[],y[].

```
from django.shortcuts import render
x=[]
y=[]
def index(request):
    return render(request,'home.html')

def inputplot(request):
    if(request.method=="POST"):
       xvalue=request.POST.get('xvalue')
       yvalue=request.POST.get('yvalue')
       x.append(xvalue)
       y.append(yvalue)
       print x
       print y
       return render(request,'inputplot.html')
       del x[:]
       del y[:]
       return render(request,'inputplot.html')
def plot(request):
       `return render(request,'plot.html',{'x':x,'y':y})
```

I want the lists in plot.html but when i append data to the list it automatically add some characters. For example i input a number 12 for x value, but this number appears in the list as [u'12'].

Why this happened?

pls give me a solution or show me another method to read user data and plot the values.??? Help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data from your `request.POST` is a string here.   The `[u'12']` is telling you that [it's a unicode string.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9773151/1293222), which is why it's not plotting correctly.

Assuming they're all integers, you need something along the lines of:
 `xvalue=int(request.POST.get('xvalue'))`

Substitute with Decimal, if appropriate.

Comment: Great! If you could accept that answer I'd appreciate it. :)