# Skipping the null values in python

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I'm trying to read the data from excel sheet 
using the code

```
import xlrd

input= raw_input("put in the path name for file")
book=xlrd.open_workbook(input)
print book.nsheets
print book.sheet_names()

ws=book.sheet_by_index(0)
for rows in range(0,14):
    data= ws.row_values(rows)
    print data
```

and the answer I'm getting is this

```
[u'', u'', u'', u'', u'RS2 WW10 BKC', u'', u'RS2 WW23.2 BKC', u'']
[u'Slno', u'Title', u'Platform Target(W)', u'SoC Target (mW)', u'Platform Power(
W)', u'SoC  Power (W)', u'Platform Power(W)', u'SoC  Power (W)']
[u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'']
[1.0, u'Display Idle', 4766.0, 80.0, 5013.0, 145.0, 2714.0, 2422.0]
[2.0, u'VPB 1080p_30fps', 4999.0, 615.0, 4726.0, 1219.0, 2800.0, 2470.0]
[3.0, u'VPB _4k2k-H265', 5888.0, 1231.0, 5244.0, 1619.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[4.0, u'Connected standby', 181.0, 17.0, 266.0, 124.0, 176.0, 74.0]
[5.0, u'S3', 193.0, 52.0, 132.0, 94.0, 3719.0, 3245.0]
[6.0, u'Angry Bird', 6804.0, 2118.0, 7730.0, 3860.0, 2668.0, 2387.0]
[7.0, u'Browsing bench', 6209.0, 474.0, 5851.0, 1241.0, 3207.0, 2813.0]
[8.0, u'Dash Streaming', 5411.0, 663.0, 5576.0, 1842.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[9.0, u'MM14', 5651.0, 973.0, 7504.0, 3024.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[10.0, u'Miracast-VPB_Extend', 5072.0, 4007.0, 4196.0, 3081.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[11.0, u'Miracast-Idle', 5389.0, 756.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

is there any way to skip the 
[u'', u'', u'', u'', values so that I can save the rest of  data in another variable.

Answer: the issue was that I was directly fetching the value being unicode it got encoded with it. but if I print the index value then it comes without the u.

so, I directly used print data[0], data[1],data[2]

Hope this explains

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing u in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773121/removing-u-in-list)

Comment: ok, so in the end of code I added **print data.encode('utf-8')** and it is giving this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mine.py", line 17, in <module>
    print data.encode('utf-8')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: Iterate through each element. You can **encode** and **decode** a string, but can a list ? ;)

Comment: but won't iterating through each element remove the u values from the normal string. And I think if it works on string it should work on list @IMCoins

Comment: @user9144536 What's your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filtered_data = list(filter(None, data))`
or you can loop over list to check if it is empty with 
`filtered_data = [a for a in data if a != ""]`
then you can print filtered_data to see result.

Comment: got this error,      File "mine.py", line 18
    print list
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax  can you tell me how to write it or where exactly I'm going wrong    _data= ws.row_values(rows)
 list(filter(None, data)
 print list_

Comment: `for rows in range(0,14):
    data= ws.row_values(rows)
    print list(filter(None, data))`
this works for me with your inputs, you didn't assign list(filter(None, data)) as I see above.

Comment: I updated my answer and set filtered data to a variable as asked above.

Comment: it somewhat worked, got this as answer [u'RS2 WW10 BKC', u'RS2 WW23.2 BKC']
[u'Slno', u'Title', u'Platform Target(W)', u'SoC Target (mW)', u'Platform Power(
W)', and so on, could you tell me @DenizKaplan how to the u and the bracket and the quotes part

Comment: The `u` part is for unicode string, but you can replace all brackets with `string.replace` method. `u'Platform Power( W)'.replace("(","").replace(")","")` will return `u"Platform Power W"` the quotes are also represents string type. I hope this will help you, if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: should I put in an if condition for that because there is going a lot, I mean huge amounts of data, and doing it one at a time will be difficult and time consuming. Also I want to get rid of the "u" character that is coming infront of every character. You earlier loop helped but no completely. Also in the loop can you tell me what is x?

Comment: I've changed 'x' with 'data'. You cannot exactly get rid of the "u" character (but you won't see if you print any element in array), because it's python's unicode string literal (not exactly a character in your data). You can use replace as `filtered_data = [a.replace("(","").replace(")","") for a in data if a != ""]` without if statement. If you have big data and want something else for time consumption, I can recommend https://pandas.pydata.org/

Comment: Thanks @DenizKaplan, you're last  line gave me an idea, I'll edit and post the solution