# Removing 'u' from a list of dicts in Python

Tags: python, unicode

I'm trying to get some data from the api using python requests. My code is as follows:

```
response = settings.get_request_with_token(settings.api_url, settings.token)
dashboard = json.loads(response.decode("utf-8"))
```

And `get_request_with_token` is as follows:

```
def post_request_with_token(url, api_key, json_payload={}):
    r = requests.post(url, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + api_key}, data=json_payload)
    return r.content
```

In my `response` I get the following result:

```
'[{"id":1,"title":"Name","uri":"db/name","type":"dash-db","tags":[],"isStarred":false}]'
```

I use then `json.loads` to get the following result:

```
[{u'tags': [], u'type': u'dash-db', u'title': u'Name', u'uri': u'db/name', u'isStarred': False, u'id': 1}]
```

But I cannot rid of **'u'** .

I tried as you can see with `.decode("utf-8")` but I get the same.

Any idea how to solve it?

**UPDATE**

I'm trying to update dashboard on Grafana and I'm getting the following error:

```
[{u'message': u"invalid character 'm' looking for beginning of value", u'classification': u'DeserializationError'}, {u'message': u'Required', u'classification': u'RequiredError', u'fieldNames': [u'Dashboard']}]
```

**UDPDATE2**

The whole script looks as follows:

```
try:
    dashboard_name = sys.argv[1]  # Get the argument

    # Get dashboard from QA organisation (we give default api token. The default token is from QA organisation from grafana)
    response = settings.get_request_with_token(settings.api_url + "search?query=" + dashboard_name, settings.token)
    dashboard = json.loads(response.decode("utf-8"))

    if len(dashboard) < 1:
        print("There is no dashboard data.")
    else:
        dashboard_data = dashboard[0]
        dashboard_uri = str(dashboard_data["uri"])  
        dashboard_details = dashboard_api.get_dashboard(dashboard_uri, settings.token)
        # Get all organisations
        all_organisations = organization_api.get_all_organizations()  # Get all organisations
        for org in all_organisations:
            if org['id'] == 28:
                org_data_list = filter(lambda organisation: organisation['grafana_id'] == org['id'], settings.organisations)
                try:
                    current_org_api_key = org_data_list[0]['api_key']

                    result = dashboard_api.add_dashboard(current_org_api_key, dashboard_details["dashboard"])
                    print(result)
                    pdb.set_trace()
                except:
                    pass
except IndexError:
    print("Please provide dashboard name!")
```

Function `get_request_with_token` looks as follows:

```
def get_request_with_token(url, api_key):
    r = requests.get(url, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + api_key})
    return r.content
```

Function `get_dashboard` looks as follows:

```
def get_dashboard(board_uri, token):
    response = settings.get_request_with_token(settings.api_url + "dashboards/{0}".format(board_uri), token)
    return json.loads(response.encode("utf-8"))
```

Function `add_dashboard` looks as follows:

```
def add_dashboard(token, json_payload):
    response = settings.post_request_with_token(settings.api_url + "dashboards/db", token, json_payload)
    return json.loads(response)
```

And function `post_request_with_token` looks as follows:

```
def post_request_with_token(url, api_key, json_payload={}):
    r = requests.post(url, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + api_key, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, data=json_payload)
    return r.content
```

Comment: 'u' just stands for Unicode. I don't think it will cause any problems

Comment: @Rakesh It causing the problems unfortunately

Comment: 'u' just stands for Unicode; it's not causing problems. Post your error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784148/understanding-repr-function-in-python and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773121/removing-u-in-list. You would not `decode()` unicode, as it is already decoded. You'd `encode()` when you need the bytes.

Comment: post your complete script, please?

Comment: have you tried `ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(list))` ? here the list is your final result gets from json.loads

Comment: @IljaEverilä with `.encode("utf-8")` I get the same.

Comment: That was not meant as a solution, but just a note on unicode vs. bytes. You haven't given enough information to solve your real issue, which most probably has nothing to do with unicode vs. bytes, though it might.

Comment: I think you will get more detail here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773121/removing-u-in-list?noredirect=1&lq=1