# I want to remove u from the output file

Tags: python

I have output generated by python

```
(u'PK_LampFactoryTest',)
(u'DF__Thermosta__Enabl__7B264821',)
(u'filestream_tombstone_2073058421',)
(u'RetentionSettings',)
(u'Alarms',)
(u'syscommittab',)
```

> sqlquery = 'SELECT NAME FROM sys.objects'
>           cursor.execute(sqlquery)

```
    #conn.commit()
    for row in cursor:
        print(row)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing u in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773121/removing-u-in-list)

Comment: The u simply indicates that it is unicode

Comment: Your `row` is a tuple. If you simply print it, Python will print the `repl` of the tuple, that is, what you would have to type in Python source to create an equivalent data structure. That includes the fact that `row` is a 1-tuple containing a Unicode string. If you don't like the formatting, don't ask `print()` to print the whole data structure. Just print the data you want to see: for example, `print(row[0])`.

Comment: @BoarGules Okay got it . I want to get the details of schema . I mean db structure without any data so if i will print(row[0]) . will it cover all the schema

Comment: @A.Ranjan Sorry, that question is DBMS-specific. In other DBMSs that table may be called something else, or may not be a table at all. So I don't know for sure what your query returns or how your code should handle what it gets. I can guess, of course, but in my experience educated guesses are not specific enough for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
import json, ast

for row in cursor:
    print(ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(row)))
```

Comment: It removed the u but it gave   ['DF__PluginApp__Admin__7908F585']
['ServiceBrokerQueue']
['LampFactoryTest']
I want only name .no special character . Is there any way .

Comment: What do you mean with `no special character`? could you provide an example?

Comment: ['sysrscols']
 here I dont want bracket and colon just the name . I have used python script to get the details of schema from sql server

Comment: wouldn't that help if you replace `row` by `row[0]` in `print` statement?

Answer (score 1):

The u simply means that it is unicode.
A simple fix for you will be

```
for row in cursor:
     print(row.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
```

But thats without understanding the bigger picture of your code and will just make that print statement look nice (by encoding the string)