# How to decode json unicode string in python?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8

How can I print `decoded_json` below so that the emoji appears?

```
>>> raw_json = '"smile "'
>>> decoded_json = cjson.decode(raw_json)
>>> decoded_json
u'smile \xf0\x9f\x98\x8a'

>>> print decoded_json
smile ð

>>> print 'smile \xf0\x9f\x98\x8a' # u' removed
smile
```

It seems like `cjson.decode` returns a `u'` unicode string. That unicode string has the correct byte representation of the emoji, but when the string is printed some other character appears instead of the emoji. 
When I print the same string with `u'` removed, it works.

Is there something I can do to `decoded_json` so that it will print the emoji?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing u in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773121/removing-u-in-list)

Comment: What is cjson? Why are you still on an ancient Python version that will be end of life end of this year?

Comment: Anyway raw bytes in a Unicode string is never correct, that's not the correct representation. Which bytes are in raw_json?

Answer (score 2):

Add the proper coding on top of your `.py` files and use the `json` module.

**Python used:** (as yours)

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.14+
```

**Code:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json

raw_json = '"smile "'
decoded_json = json.loads(raw_json)
print decoded_json
print 'smile \xf0\x9f\x98\x8a'
```

**output:**

```
python unicode.py
smile 
smile
```

Answer (score 1):

Use built-in `json` module:

```
import json
raw = '{"": "smile"}'
print(json.loads(raw))
```

[image]

Comment: You are using Python 3, he has this tagged 2 for some reason :-(

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't notice that