# u's in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Running the following code in Python 2.7:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dates = pd.date_range('20190102', periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), index=dates, columns=list('ABCD'))
print df.columns
```

produces this output:

```
Index([u'A', u'B', u'C', u'D'], dtype='object')
```

From other sources I gather that these are unicode labels. How do I get rid of them?

Comment: Does this work for you? `df.columns = [str(x) for x in df.columns]`

Comment: use python 3 ;)

Comment: @adrtam yes that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

df.columns = [str(col_name) for col_name in df.columns]

More information can be found in this answer:

[Removing u in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773121/removing-u-in-list)

Answer (score 0):

you can also use 'str()' on the parsed data