# How to download plain-text from Google spreadsheet cell?

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

I'm using gspread module to login to a 1) Google spreadsheet 2) download a column of cells 3) print/save them to a text file.

I can use string filtering, but it removes some commas that I want to keep. So using string filters is not an option. The format gives plain-text when I use "val = worksheet.acell('B1').value". But it doesn't give me plain-text when I use "cell = worksheet.cell(1, value_render_option='FORMULA').value"

I'm using burnash gspread API to login and pull the data.

```py
sheet = spreadsheet.open('Spreadsheet Name').worksheet('Worksheet Name')

col = sheet.col_values(1, value_render_option='FORMULA')

print str(col)
```

The problem is, it gives the values as ['[u\'Text in Row 1', u\'Text in Row 2', u\'Text in Row 3'] instead of "Text in Row 1Text in Row 2Text in Row 3" (which is what I want the output to show)

Comment: Do you want to remove `/u` ?

Comment: @LakshyaSrivastava I want to remove [u\' and anything that's not included in the cell. Basically I just want to download only the text that's inside the cells within a single column.

Comment: you can use .encode("utf-8") , or .encode('ascii', 'ignore') to remove u

Comment: Is the output like this [`[ ....].....],  a list of list ?

Comment: after that just `" ".join(str(x) for x in above_list)`

Comment: @LakshyaSrivastava Thank you for your response. Can you please post a complete code of what you're explaining? I'm testing, it but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**'u'** is the text representation of the corresponding Unicode string.

Suppose u' occurs in a variable test, it could be removed by:

`test.encode("utf-8")`

Checkout [This link for more ways.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773121/removing-u-in-list)

And for List like

> test_list = ['Text in Row 1','Text in Row 2','Text in Row 3']

Run the following code:

```
test_list = ['Text in Row 1','Text in Row 2','Text in Row 3']

output_list = " ".join(str(x) for x in test_list)

print(output_list)
```

And the output would be :

> Text in Row 1 Text in Row 2 Text in Row 3

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!! You are amazing!!!!! This solved my problem!!!! I also learned a lot from your help!!!